# Adding all the bits of a std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

I want to add all the bits of a n bit std_logic_vector. What would be the simplest way to do that?
for ex: A<=10011011. Result should be 101.
I can call a ripple carry adder in a loop.  but is there any other simple way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you post the code that you wrote and tell us what you think is wrong with it

Comment: How do you want to add the bits? is it for converting it to an integer value? is it for finding how many 1's the vector contain?

Comment: You can do this is a neat way in using recursive functions in VHDL - it results in an adder tree that goes through all the bits (trying to vaguely remember how it was done).

Comment: Just try it. It is pretty straightforward. Remember: even a ripple carry will be mapped to FPGA LUTs.

Comment: It's called Hamming weight.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "simple". If by "simple" you mean the simplest code then a simple for loop will suffice. If you want the fastest hardware possible, then you want the adder tree that was mentioned. But the coding for that is a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
-- Loop-based
function hw_loop(v: std_logic_vector) return natural is
  variable h: natural;
begin
  h := 0;
  for i in v'range loop
    if v(i) = '1' then
      h := h + 1;
    end if;
  end loop;
  return h;
end function hw_loop;
...
-- Log-tree-based, using a recursive function:
function hw_tree(v: std_logic_vector) return natural is
  constant size: natural := v'length;
  constant vv: std_logic_vector(size - 1 downto 0) := v;
  variable h: natural;
begin
  h := 0;
  if size = 1 and vv(0) = '1' then
    h := 1;
  elsif size > 1 then
    h := hw_tree(vv(size - 1 downto size / 2)) + hw_tree(vv(size / 2 - 1 downto 0));
  end if;
  return h;
end function hw_tree;
...
signal A: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal B0, B1: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
...
B0 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(hw_loop(A), 3));
B1 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(hw_tree(A), 3));
...
```

Notes:

- You should use `std_ulogic` and `std_ulogic_vector` instead of `std_logic` and `std_logic_vector`.
- With some logic synthesizers the log-tree solution will produce a better design (faster, same size) than the loop. With some others, the result will be the same.